# How do I alternate between two images on iOS with UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I would like to alternate between two images on a screen at a gradually decreasing rate.  I'm not sure if this qualifies as gaming, or animation, but I'm just displaying a list of barcodes that will be scanned by a continuous scanner.

Code that doesn't swap the images (in practice)

```
        int delay = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i+=100)
        {
            delay += i;

            Console.WriteLine("a");
            imageBarcode.Image = barcode;

            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(delay);

            Console.WriteLine("b");
            imageBarcode.Image = barcode2;

            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(delay);

        }
```

What do I need to do in order to make the UI update with the new image?

Answer (score 0):

You can animate an image like a GIF

Here is a sample code:

```
- (void)startAnimation
{
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"img_one", @"img_two"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++)
    {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    _imageView.animationImages = images;
    _imageView.animationDuration = durationYouWant;

    [_ivSpeaker startAnimating];
}
```

The `durationYouWant` variable will be the duration that the whole animation will take.

The animation will be unlimited unless you call this

```
- (void)stopAnimation
{
    [_imageView stopAnimating];
}
```

Hope this helps. :)